# How to convert dict_keys to an integer

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the keys are integers, and are in sequence.  From time to time, I need to remove older entries from the dictionary.  However, when I try to do this, I run into a "dict_keys" error.

```
    '<=' not supported between instances of 'dict_keys' and 'int'
```

When I try to cast the value to an int, I'm told that's not supported.

```
    int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict_keys'
```

I see answers here saying to use a list comprehension.  However, as there may be a million entries in this dictionary, I'm hoping there is some way to perform the cast without having to perform it on the entire list of keys.

```
    import numpy as np

    d = dict()
    for i in range(100):
        d[i] = i+10

    minId = int(np.min(d.keys()))
    while(minId <= 5):
        d.pop(minId)
        minId += 1
```

Comment: Did you look at the output of `np.min(d.keys())`? It doesn't return a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert `dict_keys` to `int`. That's not a thing that makes sense, anyway. Your problem is that `np.min` needs a sequence, and the return value of `d.keys()` is not a sequence.

For taking the minimum of an iterable, use the regular Python [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min), not `np.min`. However, calling `min` in a loop is an inefficient way to do things. [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) could help, or you could find a better data structure than a dict.

Comment: I would only be calling pop inside a loop.  But using standard min will fix it.  I saw the min(a,b) variant in the docs, but somehow missed the min(iterable).

Answer (score 0):

You want a list is you want to use numpy:

```
minId = np.min(list(d))
```

but actually you can use the builtin `min` here, which nows how to iterate, and for a dict, the iteration happens over keys anyway

```
minId = min(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) and `pop` the oldest key-value pair. An advantage to use an `OrderedDict` is that it remembers the order that keys were first inserted. In this code, the first key will always be the minimum in the `OrderedDict` d. When you use `popitem(last=False)`, it simply removes the oldest or first key-value pair.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for i in range(100):
    d[i] = i+10
d.popitem(last=False) #removes the earliest key-value pair from the dict
print(d)
```

If you'd like to remove the oldest 5 key-value pairs, extract these key-value pairs into a list of tuples and then use `popitem(last=False)` again to remove them from the top(heap analogy):

```
a = list(d.items())[:5] #get the first 5 key-value pairs in a list of tuples
for i in a:
    if i in d.items():        
        print("Item {} popped from dictionary.".format(i))
        d.popitem(last=False)

#Output:
Item (0, 10) popped from dictionary.
Item (1, 11) popped from dictionary.
Item (2, 12) popped from dictionary.
Item (3, 13) popped from dictionary.
Item (4, 14) popped from dictionary.
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up-vote.  It's good to know about the OrderedDict, though for my situation, I think python min() on a regular dictionary will suffice.